# Special string like \LaTeX

Tags: logos

I am looking for a list of all the strings the render special in LaTeX, for example `\latex` and `\python`, I believe are both special. Are there others? Is there a list somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: That links helps a bit, but isn't `\python` one too? that's not on the list. I'm actually looking more for programming languages that have special latex formatting.

Comment: What's special about the typeset name "Python"? The official logo is available [here](http://www.python.org/community/logos/). This is used as graphics.

Comment: I must be nuts, I was dead sure `\python` had special formatting. clearly I'm wrong, sorry about that. So its just TeX related string like `\LaTex` the format special then?

Comment: Why should there be a `\python` command providing a textlike logo of Python? All such commands as `\LaTeX` etc. (see the link Heiko Oberdiek provided) deal more or less with `LaTeX` itself.

Comment: You can always use `texdoc` on any package that might provide such commands. They will usually be documented there.

Comment: Here is a (typographically bad) example of such a `\python` command, where I have played around with raiseboxes and kerning: `\providecommand{\python}{%
P\raisebox{-0.2em}{\kern -0.3em y}\raisebox{0.2em}{t}\raisebox{-0.3em}{\kern -0.32em h}\raisebox{-0.3em}{o}\raisebox{-0.5em}{n}
}%`